# If I get an ssl certificate - can I still access my web pages using http?

Tags: ssl, https

If I get an ssl certificate - can I still access my web pages using http (instead of https) so they'll load faster?

Or perhaps have the ssl for only certain pages on my site? (I'm using web hosting, perhaps it matters.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. When you're setting up the certificate, you can configure your server to listen on port 443 (for SSL, where it will serve your certificate) as well as port 80 (where normal HTTP traffic will go). For pages where you absolutely want to have SSL, you'll need to force the user to visit the https:// URL.